# How to set webview animation come like modalviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to set webview animation come as  back to up presentmodalview controller..

How can i do that?

Comment: Please, try to edit your question and explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create an `UIViewController` which holds the `UIWebView` and present the `UIViewController` as modal.

This way you dont have to muck around with view animations and keeping track of the views.